# When is an apkovl file applied?

Tags: alpine-linux

When booting Alpine, one can specify an overlay file via the kernel command line argument [`apkovl=`](https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/PXE_boot#Specifying_an_apkovl). This overlay file is fetched and expanded over the rootfs.

What is responsible for doing this? When during boot does it happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initramfs contains the script `/init` which is generated from [`initramfs-init.in`](https://github.com/alpinelinux/mkinitfs/blob/master/initramfs-init.in).

The script first downloads the overlay file if it is on the network. Then it calls the function `unpack_apkovl` which optionally decrypts the overlay file, and then untars it over the rootfs.